# Issue copying small amount of data using SSE intrinsics

Tags: c++, sse, simd

I've looked at similar questions here and tried to use similar code, but am going wrong somewhere.. This is just a learning exercise by the way.  Here is the code:

```
struct alignas(16) Data
{
    union
    {
      int field1;
      int field2;
      int field3;
      int field4;
      int field5;
      int field6;
      int field7;
      int field8;
      __m128 v[2];
   };
};

void copy((__m128* __restrict b, const __m128* __restrict a)
{
    *b++ = *a++;
    *b++ = *a++;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
   Data dst={0};
   Data src={0};
   src.field1=1;
   src.field2=500;
   src.field3=200;
   src.field4=393;
   src.field5=29383;
   src.field6=3838;
   src.field7=128484;
   src.field8=111;

   copy(dst.v,src.v);


   std::cout<<" before copy   dst.field1=" << dst.field1 <<" dst.field2=" << dst.field2 << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

It's showing 0 for both field1 and field2 before the copy, but both are 111 after the copy?  I'm fairly new to c++ so it appears it's copying the last 32 bits of the struct over 64 bits of the dst struct, but not sure why?

Comment: It's not being used anywhere..  Just playing around with sse. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your union is incorrect, it has 1 integer or your array of `__m128`. `field1`, `field2` etc all point to the same memory. All your assignments apart from your last one to `field8` are being overwritten.

You could use this instead:

```
struct alignas(16) Data
{
    union
    {
      int fields[8];
      __m128 v[2];
   };
};
```

Comment: @SubliminalBroccoli: Or `union { struct { int field1, field2, ...; }; __m128i v[2]; };` I forget if an anonymous struct is allowed there, inside the union.  BTW, I'd normally just use `_mm_load_si128` instead of a union.  Or with a new enough compiler, just do `dst = src` and let the compiler do struct assignment efficiently.  (gcc 6 and earlier copy structs one member at a time, though, which is usually worse.  See both on https://godbolt.org/g/sC94aG.)